# Mongodb insert null date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mail Schema:

```
var mail = new mongoose.Schema({
    globalId: {type: String, index: true, unique: true},
    from: {type: String, required: true},
    beginDate: {type: Date, required: true},
    endDate: {type: Date},
    source: {type: String},
    address: {type: String},
    subject: {type: String, required: true},
    text: {type: String},
    note: {type: String},
    files: [
        {
            fileName: {type: String},
            fileSize: {type: Number},
            fileType: {type: String}
        }
    ]
});
```

When I try to save new mail with endDate is null I have the following error

```
Mail validation failed: endDate: Cast to Date failed for value "null"
```

Comment: save  new mail with endDate as `undefined`

Comment: Don't pass end date while saving new data

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are trying to save the schema with an invalid endDate.

If you do not want to save a date simply leave it out from the object. For instance all you need to provide for your schema at a minimum is:

```
const newMail = mail.create({
    globalId: "1234",
    from: "Jack",
    beginDate: new Date(),
    subject: "Random subject",
});
```

If you tried to do something like,

`endDate: null`

this will fail as it is expecting a `Date()` object or nothing at all.

Answer (score 4):

As you have mentioned that you are storing `endDate` as `null` as String. That will definitely fail because your schema expecting a date and you are storing String.

Multiple ways you can approach:

1. Avoid `endDate` from JSON object. *(You will not have endDate key in MongoDB)*
2. set `endDate: undefined` that will automatically be ignored. *(You will not have endDate key in MongoDB)*
3. Set `endDate: null` ***not in String*** *(You will have endDate key as `null` value)*

Below one will not work:

```
var testObj = {
    ct: "null", // null as String value
    name: "Foo"
}
```

But this one will definitely work:

```
var testObj = {
    ct: null, // null as value
    name: "Foo"
}
```

**Tested on below version:**

MongoDB *v3.2.18* 
Mongoose *v4.10.8*

*Another point I want to add here is storing `key: null` will consume resources. If your requirement is not dependent on `null` values, I would like to use not to store a key in the database rather storing as `null`.*

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by setting the default date to `undefined`. It will not show up on creation of your object. That is fine as it is now a frontend problem. If a key does not exist the frontend will default to undefined. If it remains undefined it will not be saved in your database. Avoid having a default `null` I have made that mistake too!

```
mail = {
  endDate: {
   type: Date,
   default: undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your schema you can mention the type as `endDate : { type: Date || null}` and wherever you feel like assign the value as null if date is not there OR you can even add default as null to schema.